# Why Router link does not work in Firefox and IE but working fine in Safari and Chrome in vue js?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

```html
Here is my html code :
  <button type="button"  class="btn btn-default btn-block" v-for="x in filterName" v-on:click="passuserid(x.rsid)"> <router-link v-bind:to="'/combo/'"><b>{{x.last_name}}</b> {{x.first_name}}

            </router-link></button>
```

And Here is the routes code:

```js
export const routes =[
    { path:'', component: ContentArea},
    { path:'/combo/', component: Comparison }
  ];
```

Comment: It only supports ES5-compliant browsers (IE8 and below are not supported). What version of firefox are you using?

Comment: firefox 56.0 (64 bit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use li instead of the button.

```html
<li class="btn btn-default btn-block" v-for="x in filterName" v-on:click="passuserid(x.rsid)">
               <router-link to="/combo">{{x.last_name}}</b> {{x.first_name}}</router-link>
             </li>
```